# One email user keeps disconnecting from our exchange server

Tags: networking, email, exchange-2010, outlook-2003

I have one user who keeps reporting that Outlook keeps disconnecting from our email server. All other users are fine.

Our email server is running Exchange 2010 and the client is running Outlook 2003. The disconnection only lasts a moment.

I have checked for logs on the client and Exchange server and can not see any reason for the disconnect, On the Client I get EventId 26 telling me Outlook has disconnected and reconnected but no reason why.

Can anyone give me some suggestions of things to try and track down where the problem could be?

--Update--

I have found the following log file C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Logging\RPC Client Access which suggests that it is a problem with RPC sessions.

Excerpt is below

```
2013-01-31T15:21:24.015Z,6413,15,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,,0,00:00:00,"BS=Conn:24,HangingConn:0,AD:$null/$null/0%,CAS:$null/$null/2%,AB:$null/$null/0%,RPC:$null/$null/1%,FC:$null/0,Policy:ClientThrottlingPolicy2,Norm[Resources:(Mdb)Mailbox Database 0765959540(Health:-1%,HistLoad:0),(Mdb)Public Folder Database 1945427388(Health:-1%,HistLoad:0),];GC:6/1/0;",
2013-01-31T15:21:24.015Z,6413,16,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,PublicLogoff,0,00:00:00,LogonId: 1,
2013-01-31T15:21:24.015Z,6413,16,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,,,00:00:00,"BS=Conn:24,HangingConn:0,AD:$null/$null/0%,CAS:$null/$null/2%,AB:$null/$null/0%,RPC:$null/$null/1%,FC:$null/0,Policy:ClientThrottlingPolicy2,Norm[Resources:(Mdb)Mailbox Database 0765959540(Health:-1%,HistLoad:0),(Mdb)Public Folder Database 1945427388(Health:-1%,HistLoad:0),];GC:6/1/0;",
2013-01-31T15:21:24.015Z,6417,5,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,OwnerLogoff,0,00:00:00,LogonId: 0,
2013-01-31T15:21:24.015Z,6417,5,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,,0x6BA (rpc::Exception),00:02:54.7668000,Budget Highs [AD = 0][CAS = 3][RPC = 1] Session Throttled Count = 0; SessionDropped,"RpcEndPoint: [ServerUnavailableException] Connection must be re-established -> [SessionDeadException] Connection doesn't have any open logons, but has client activity. This may be masking synchronization stalls. Dropping a connection."
2013-01-31T15:21:24.015Z,6420,7,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,DelegateLogoff,0,00:00:00,LogonId: 0,
2013-01-31T15:21:24.031Z,6420,7,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,,,00:00:00.0156000,Budget Highs [AD = 0][CAS = 3][RPC = 1] Session Throttled Count = 0,
2013-01-31T15:21:24.031Z,6420,7,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,Disconnect,0,00:02:54.2364000,,
2013-01-31T15:21:24.031Z,6419,5,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,OwnerLogoff,0,00:00:00,LogonId: 0,
2013-01-31T15:21:24.031Z,6419,5,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,,,00:00:00,Budget Highs [AD = 0][CAS = 3][RPC = 1] Session Throttled Count = 0,
2013-01-31T15:21:24.031Z,6419,5,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,Disconnect,0,00:02:54.4392000,,
2013-01-31T15:21:24.031Z,6416,7,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,DelegateLogoff,0,00:00:00,LogonId: 0,
2013-01-31T15:21:24.031Z,6416,7,/o=EUROSAFEUK/ou=first administrative group/cn=Recipients/cn=andy,,OUTLOOK.EXE,11.0.8303.0,Classic,,,ncacn_ip_tcp,,,,00:00:00,Budget Highs [AD = 0][CAS = 3][RPC = 1] Session Throttled Count = 0,
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction for a solution?

Comment: maybe it has to do with the Client Throttling Policies in Exchange 2010

Comment: Thanks I am investigating the Throttling Policies which lead me to find the RPC CLient logs. Which mention lots of Disconnects!

Comment: Where are these log - I am just curious?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Logging\RPC Client Access

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to launch outlook with the /rcpdiag ?

```
 # outlook.exe /rpcdiag
```

Do you have **OutlookAnywhere** installed on your server?

Did you check the network connectivity from the client?

```
 # ping -t -l 1500 echangeserver
```

Should have 0% loss.

Sorry, I thought I read Outlook 2013 ... 
There is no rpcdiag on 2003

Answer (score 0):

Check the System event log on the PC for network-related events, specifically ones that say link down, or link up, or link speed negotiated. This would indicate you have a faulty network connection to that PC. Outlook is very sensitive to the quality of the network connection so when the network link is lost (for even just a second) Outlook disconnects.